# SQL query timings

Tags: sql, select

Does it take more time to create a table using select as statement or to just run the select statement? Is the time difference too large or can it be neglected?

For example between

```
create table a
as select * from b
where c = d;
```

and

```
select * from b
where c = d;
```

which one should run faster and can the time difference be neglected?

Comment: Do you need to create a table?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am running the code on hive terminal. It is not necessary to create the table, but I just wanted to know the timing difference.

Comment: Don't create a table if you don't need to. This incurs more work for the database (storage management, ...), which is wasted if you don't need this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the table will take more time.  There is more overhead.  If you look at the metadata for your database, you will find lots of tables or views that contain information about tables.  In particular, the table names and column names need to be stored.

That said, the *data processing* effort is pretty similar.  However, there might be overhead in storing the result set in *permanent* storage rather than in the data structures needed for a result set.  In fact, the result set may never need to be stored "on disk" (i.e. permanently).  But with a table creation, that is needed.

Depending on the database, the two queries might also be optimized differently.  The `SELECT` query might be optimized to return the *first* row as fast as possible.  The `CREATE` query might be optimized to return *all* rows as fast as possible.  Also, the `SELECT` quite might just look faster if your database and interface start returning rows when they first appear.

I should point out that under most circumstances, the overhead might not really be noticeable.  But, you can get other errors with the `create table` statement that you would not get with just the `select`.  For instance, the table might already exist.  Or duplicate column names might pose a problem (although some databases don't allow duplicate column names in result sets either).